# How to convert UPC-E to UPC-A?

Tags: c#, barcode

What is the formula for converting UPC-E barcodes to UPC-A barcodes? Better yet would be some C# code, C#esque pseudocode, or even just in an "English" expository way.

Comment: This is now answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/31539006/2568535

Comment: Thanks; funny how the same question went from off-topic to apparently on-topic.

Comment: Yeah. I initially attempted to edit your question requesting that a mod re-open it as a useful and popular question for which I had an answer pre-cooked based on http://stackoverflow.com/a/31079071/2568535
That way we would have both benefited from the reputation points. Alas, it wasn't to be as this edit was rejected... Raising the question again myself was the best I could do!

Comment: All's fair in love, war, Patriots football, and Stack Overflow! (Note: I am decidedly *not* a Patriots fan! Go, Packers!!!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ctrl+F for "Converting UPC-A to UPC-E" at http://www.taltech.com/barcodesoftware/symbologies/upc . It explains all the cases in a better format than I can paste here.

Comment: That's a good link for checking my calculations against, plus it has a source code download (even though it is VB - bleh!), so I'll give you the answer. Say hi to the monkeys for me.

Comment: Just to point out that the linked-to description of the conversion process does not handle UPCs with a number system other than 0. Thanks.